# Authenticate user using passport-local from static json data

Tags: json, node.js, passport-local

I need to authenticate users from a json file using passport-local in node.js .
I tried using MongoDb as user data storage and it worked well.
But now I need to try using a Json file as user details storage and passportlocal need to fetch data from the file to authenticate the user.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

let's assume this is your main app

```
var db = require('./db.js');
var passport = require('passport');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var express = require('express')();
express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) 
{
    db.getUser(username, function (err, user) 
    {
        if (err) 
            return done(err,null);
        else
            return done(null, user);
    });
}));
// Serilize authenticated user into the request so they can access callback functions
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) 
{
  done(null, user);
});
// deserilize authonticated user so the callback function can read thier data
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) 
{
    done(null, user);
});

express.post('/auth',passport.authenticate('local', {session:false,failureRedirect:"/accessdenied"}),function(req,res)
{
    res.send("authenticated");
});

express.get('/accessdenied',function(req,res)
{
    res.send("access denied");
});

express.listen(4321);
```

and this is your module on the same folder that fetch users from the json file

```
var fs = require('fs');

exports.getUser = function(user,cb)
{
    fs.readFile('users.json','utf8',function(err,data)
    {
        if(err)
            cb(err,null);
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var users = JSON.parse(data);
                if(users[user] != undefined)
                {
                    cb(null,users[user]);
                }
                else
                {
                    cb(null);
                }
            }
            catch(e)
            {
                cb(e,null)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

and this is the structure of your users.json file on the same folder

```
{
    "user@example.com":{"firstName":"abdullah","lastName":"Shahin","email":"user@example.com","password":"234","age":"28"},
    "user2@example.com":{"firstName":"Nick","lastName":"Persons","email":"user2@example.com","password":"234","age":"27"}
}
```

the main parameter works as primary key, and it has to be unique to fetch the user info based on that username, I assumed its email address.

hope it helps

Comment: If the JSON file doesn't change (which "static" means to me), you can just use `require('users.json')` once, instead of reading the file each time a user needs to be authenticated.

Comment: No, you can't do this, you may save the file as .js file, and export an object with that user info, that will work

Comment: `require()` has built-in support for JSON files, try it.